# Mysql inserts blank row after inserting row with data (in Chrome)

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

**Seems to be a browser issue, as in firefox it is working fine but not in chrome.**

Why is it that when I submit my php form to insert data into a mysql db table, then check the table. I see my newly created row with the data in it and also an extra row with nothing in it?

**My controller:**

```
    function Admin() {
       parent::Controller();

       $this->dx_auth->check_uri_permissions();

       $this->load->model('alert_model');
       $data['rows'] = $this->alert_model->check($num_results=4);
       $this->load->view('includes/header', $data);
    }

    function index() {
       $this->load->view('admin/notifications');
       $this->load->view('includes/footer');
    }

    function sendalert() {
       $info = array(
           'msg_author'  => $this->input->post('msg_author'),
           'msg_date'    => $this->input->post('msg_date'),
           'msg_subject' => $this->input->post('msg_subject'),
           'msg_content' => $this->input->post('msg_content')
       );

       $this->send_notification->send($info);
       $this->index();
    }
```

**My Model:**

```
    function send($info) {
       $this->db->insert('msg', $info);
       return;
    }
```

**My View:**

```
<?php echo form_open('admin/sendalert'); ?>

    <label for="msg_subject">Subject</label>
    <input type="text" name="msg_subject" id="msg_subject" />

    <label for="msg_date">Date</label>
    <input type="text" name="msg_date" id="msg_date" />

    <label for="msg_author">From</label>
    <input type="text" name="msg_author" id="msg_author" />

    <label for="msg_content">Content</label>
    <input type="text" name="msg_content" id="msg_content" />

    <input type="submit" value="submit" />

<?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

Thanks

Comment: Does it really say `lable` and not `label`?

Comment: lol nope, my IDE automatically changed these for some reason, and forgot to change them back before pasting here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try change

```
$this->index();
```

to

```
redirect('admin/index', 'refresh');
```

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks. I'm guessing the problem was that it didn't redirect properly using $this->index(); in chrome.

Answer (score 0):

Code posted looks good, but maybe the problem is with:

```
$this->index();
```

can you post the index() controller function as well?

Answer (score 0):

Also check your logs if there's not a second request send to the server, that for some reason is rewritten to index.php. Most common is a missing image, a nasty one to find is the request for favicon.ico.